# Using openssl via openssl_encrypt and openssl_decrypt in php gives error

Tags: php, openssl

I have this code in page A:

```
<?php

$token = // 64 chars alphanumerical token;
$method = "aes128";
$key = "12345678";
$crypto_code = openssl_encrypt($token, $method, $key);
$encoded_crypto_code = base64_encode($crypto_code);
$target_url = "https://mysamplesite.com/use_qrcode.php?code=" . $encoded_crypto_code;

// now the code is put inside a qrcode
QRcode::png($target_url, QR_ECLEVEL_H, 3, 10);

?>
```

Then I read the code with a smartphone that takes me to page B (use_qrcode.php) where I have the following code:

```
<?php

$code_flag = 0;

if (isset($_GET["code"])){
    $encoded_crypto_code = $_GET["code"];
    $crypto_code = base64_decode($encoded_crypto_code);
    $method = "aes128";
    $key = "12345678";
    $code = openssl_decrypt($crypto_code, $method, $key);
    if (false === $code) {
        echo sprintf("OpenSSL error: %s", openssl_error_string() . "<br>");
   } else {
       echo "received code: " . $code . "<br>";
       $code_flag = 1;
   }
}

?>
```

My *if(false === $code)* catch an error, which is "*OpenSSL error: error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length*".

If I check both the base64 encoded string and the crypto string before and after sending them by QRcode, they are ok, so no problems in QR encoding and decoding nor in base64 encoding and decoding. The problem is somewhere in the OpenSSL. I am surprised since I use openssl_ encrypt and openssl_decrypt in many places all around the site, and this is the first time I face an error. If I do not use base64 encoding and decoding, the OpenSSL error is still there.

Is there any problem with the token I use?

Same result if I use some other similar tokens.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Your AES method = "aes128" is of the wrong naming and it should include the AES **mode**. For e.g. you can use the **UNSECURE ECB mode** without any initialization vector, for that the method would be $method = "aes-128-ecb", but much better is to use a random generated iv (but that will lengths the data).

Comment: Thx Michael, good suggestions